# SharedPreferences and Countdown Timer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want to save the CountDown Ttimer value into a variable so that next time the user start the Countdowntimer Activity, it to reload at the exact elapsed time as it remained.
Here is my code and I don't understand why it doesn't works. (it shows my time Textbox empty)

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   long timer = prefs.getLong("TIME", 86400000);

   new CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long elapsed) {
             System.out.print(elapsed);
             long timer2=elapsed;
             long hours = timer2 / hours_in_millies;
             timer2 %= hours_in_millies;
             long minutes = timer2 / minutes_in_millies;
             timer2 %= minutes_in_millies;
             long seconds = timer2 / seconds_in_millies;
             time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
             editor.putLong("TIME",elapsed);
             editor.commit(); 


         }
```

Comment: what do ypu get from your sysouts? SharedPreferences are working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
  prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

   xtime = System.currentTimeMillis()-prefs.getLong("TIME",System.currentTimeMillis()); 

   long timer=86400000-(xtime+prefs.getLong("TIME2",0)); 

   final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putLong("TIME2",xtime+prefs.getLong("TIME2",0));  
   editor.commit(); 


   new CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) { 

         public void onTick(long elapsed) {

             Log.d(TAG, "TIMER" + System.currentTimeMillis());
             long timer2=elapsed;
             long hours = timer2 / hours_in_millies;
             timer2 %= hours_in_millies;
             long minutes = timer2 / minutes_in_millies;
             timer2 %= minutes_in_millies;
             long seconds = timer2 / seconds_in_millies;
             time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);


         }

         public void onFinish() 
         { Intent intent = new Intent(Hug.this, Hug_Accepted.class);
        startActivity(intent);

         }

   }
   .start();    
   xtime=System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = prefs.edit();
     editor2.putLong("TIME",xtime);         
     editor2.commit(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you are updating the shared preferences quite a bit. This is probably a bad idea. It would be better to save the time stamp and the time on the timer on the onStop and then onResume calculate how much time has passed and pick it up from there.

Comment: And what will I do if the application closes?

Comment: if your application closes, onStop should be called. At that point your pref would be saved.

Comment: Should I use the editor.commit() in my Back button pressed class? Also, what will I do if the timer runs out?

Comment: I don't really now how to use your idea Pyro, can you please write a simple code on it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `timer` variable being used in ontick(), you have used `timer2` variable.
Put a logger`Log.d()` before setText() line to check the results for the variables you are using... as otherwise editText cannot be definitely **empty**

Moreover, save the time in shared preferences in onStop()  of your activity.. not on each Tick of timer!

**EDIT:**
*After the clarification of requirement from OP*

You might want to follow a different approach.. 
say when the countdown has to start.. use System.currentTimeMillis() to get the START TIME
and store it in SharedPreferences/DB.

whenever activity starts... **fetch** the START_TIME frm preferences... and start timer with initial time as **(System.currentTimeMillis - START_TIME)** and onTick() update the timer(UI). *NOTE: You won't have to update the timer value now back to SharedPreferences*

Comment: I've watched the logs and put the variable saving part in my OnBackPressed method. It seems that the problem is at long timer = prefs.getLong("TIME", 86400000); , seems like it always starts again from that 86400000.

Comment: can u show the updated code of yours... the correct way would be to in onTick() store the latest min/hrs/... in the local(activity scope) variables.. and the code to update the sharedpreferences by using those variables....

Comment: Oh, now I've found out that this isn't what I really wanted. I just wanted a countdowntimer that will continue to tick even if the activity or application closes. Can someone help me? Found an post about it but it implies using Services, which I don't know a thing about.

Comment: yes you can do it with services.. i have edited answer with an alternate approach to it..