# Keep count down after closing app

Tags: android, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

Good morning guys, please I'm building an application to run tasks every hour, and I want to show countdown. But when I left the app and came back, the count restarts.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Save it in SharedPreferences when `onStop` in called in the Activity and read it back from it inside `onStart` and continue the timer from there.

Comment: you have to save data!
please check following site! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606379/sharedpreferences-and-countdown-timer

Comment: check it following site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606379/sharedpreferences-and-countdown-timer

Comment: @red_allocator , I was able to implement the countdown with its response, however, every time I start the countdown it starts with a different time than the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

read the Data [Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) developer guide.

you can save data in sharedpreperence 
read the data 
and set data to timer in Resume